# Scipy - Cookbook - Plotting Images with Special Values - Won't work

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to run an example from the Scipy Cook Book and cannot get it to run.

I am using python 2.7 (Numpy version 1.6.2, Matplotlib 1.1.1)

The code is located at

http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Plotting_Images_with_Special_Values

```
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, normalize
    #import matplotlib.numerix as nx  #In original code changed to numpy in line below
    import numpy as nx
    from types import IntType, FloatType, ListType

    class SentinelMap(Colormap):
            def __init__(self, cmap, sentinels={}):
                    # boilerplate stuff
                    self.N = cmap.N
                    self.name = 'SentinelMap'
                    self.cmap = cmap
                    self.sentinels = sentinels
                    for rgb in sentinels.values():
                            if len(rgb)!=3:
                                    raise ValueError('sentinel color must be RGB')


            def __call__(self, scaledImageData, alpha=1):
                    # assumes the data is already normalized (ignoring sentinels)
                    # clip to be on the safe side
                    rgbaValues = self.cmap(nx.clip(scaledImageData, 0.,1.))

                    #replace sentinel data with sentinel colors
                    for sentinel,rgb in self.sentinels.items():
                            r,g,b = rgb
                            rgbaValues[:,:,0] =  nx.where(scaledImageData==sentinel, r, rgbaValues[:,:,0])
                            rgbaValues[:,:,1] =  nx.where(scaledImageData==sentinel, g, rgbaValues[:,:,1])
                            rgbaValues[:,:,2] =  nx.where(scaledImageData==sentinel, b, rgbaValues[:,:,2])
                            rgbaValues[:,:,3] =  nx.where(scaledImageData==sentinel, alpha, rgbaValues[:,:,3])

                    return rgbaValues

    class SentinelNorm(normalize):
            """
            Leave the sentinel unchanged
            """
            def __init__(self, ignore=[], vmin=None, vmax=None):
                    self.vmin=vmin
                    self.vmax=vmax

                    if type(ignore) in [IntType, FloatType]:
                            self.ignore = [ignore]
                    else:
                            self.ignore = list(ignore)


            def __call__(self, value):

                    vmin = self.vmin
                    vmax = self.vmax

                    if type(value) in [IntType, FloatType]:
                            vtype = 'scalar'
                            val = array([value])
                    else:
                            vtype = 'array'
                            val = nx.asarray(value)

                    # if both vmin is None and vmax is None, we'll automatically
                    # norm the data to vmin/vmax of the actual data, so the
                    # clipping step won't be needed.
                    if vmin is None and vmax is None:
                            needs_clipping = False
                    else:
                            needs_clipping = True

                    if vmin is None or vmax is None:
                            rval = nx.ravel(val)
                            #do this if sentinels (values to ignore in data)
                            if self.ignore:
                                    sortValues=nx.sort(rval)
                                    if vmin is None:
                                            # find the lowest non-sentinel value
                                            for thisVal in sortValues:
                                                    if thisVal not in self.ignore:
                                                            vmin=thisVal #vmin is the lowest non-sentinel value
                                                            break
                                            else:
                                                    vmin=0.
                                    if vmax is None:
                                            for thisVal in sortValues[::-1]:
                                                    if thisVal not in self.ignore:
                                                            vmax=thisVal #vmax is the greatest non-sentinel value
                                                            break
                                            else:
                                                    vmax=0.
                            else:
                                    if vmin is None: vmin = min(rval)
                                    if vmax is None: vmax = max(rval)
                    if vmin > vmax:
                            raise ValueError("minvalue must be less than or equal to maxvalue")
                    elif vmin==vmax:
                            return 0.*value
                    else:
                            if needs_clipping:
                                    val = nx.clip(val,vmin, vmax)
                            result = (1.0/(vmax-vmin))*(val-vmin)

                    # replace sentinels with original (non-normalized) values
                    for thisIgnore in self.ignore:
                            result = nx.where(val==thisIgnore,thisIgnore,result)

                    if vtype == 'scalar':
                            result = result[0]
                    return result


    if __name__=="__main__":
            import pylab
            import matplotlib.colors
            n=100

            # create a random array
            #X = nx.mlab.rand(n,n) # In original cookbook code changed to line below
            X = nx.random.rand(n,n)
            cmBase = pylab.cm.jet

            # plot it array as an image
            pylab.figure(1)
            pylab.imshow(X, cmap=cmBase, interpolation='nearest')

            # define the sentinels
            sentinel1 = -10
            sentinel2 = 10

            # replace some data with sentinels
            X[int(.1*n):int(.2*n), int(.5*n):int(.7*n)]  = sentinel1
            X[int(.6*n):int(.8*n), int(.2*n):int(.3*n)]  = sentinel2

            # define the colormap and norm
            rgb1 = (0.,0.,0.)
            rgb2 = (1.,0.,0.)
            cmap = SentinelMap(cmBase, sentinels={sentinel1:rgb1,sentinel2:rgb2,})
            norm = SentinelNorm(ignore=[sentinel1,sentinel2])

            # plot with the modified colormap and norm
            pylab.figure(2)
            pylab.imshow(X, cmap = cmap, norm=norm, interpolation='nearest')

            pylab.show()
```

However, I get an error saying

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 236, in resize
        self.show()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 239, in draw
        FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 421, in draw
        self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
        draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 898, in draw
        func(*args)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
        draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 1997, in draw
        a.draw(renderer)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
        draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 350, in draw
        im = self.make_image(renderer.get_image_magnification())
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 569, in make_image
        transformed_viewLim)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 201, in _get_unsampled_image
        x = self.to_rgba(self._A, bytes=True)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cm.py", line 214, in to_rgba
```

A web search lead me to find a comment on it, however nothing useful.

http://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg19249.html

Hope some one can help me understand the problem and identify the mistake.

Comment: Sadly, a lot of code in the cookbook is old and doesn't work any more. You've already seen it with the numpy part. I've played with it a bit and it seems the problem is in the colormap specified in the second plot. If you set it to 'jet' it does the plot. From the link you sent it looks like the colormap creation has changed since that example was written.